# Do `getrlimit()` and `setrlimit()` work by reading from and writing to `/etc/security/limits.conf`?

Tags: c, linux, limit

In Linux (e.g. Ubuntu 18.04 or other), do `getrlimit()` and `setrlimit()` work by reading from and writing to `/etc/security/limits.conf`?

I am trying to understand the relations between `getrlimit()` and `setrlimit()` and `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, it's the other way around: `/etc/security/limits.conf` controls calls made to `getrlimit` and `setrlimit`.

`getrlimit` and `setrlimit` read and write kernel state associated with the calling process.  They do not access any file at all.  Like most kernel state associated with a particular process, the resource limits are *inherited* (copied into) `fork`-ed children.

`/etc/security/limits.conf` is never modified automatically (except possibly by a system upgrade); it's intended for the sysadmin to edit, by hand.

The [`login`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1.html) program (technically, the [pam_limits](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_limits.8.html) module that it may load, and does load in Ubuntu 18's default configuration) reads `/etc/security/limits.conf`, and uses the information in that file to make a series of calls to [`setrlimit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html), establishing resource limits for the user's initial shell.  Those resource limits then inherit to all processes started by the shell, and so on transitively.

Comment: Thanks. Does bash's `ulimit` also work by reading and writing from and to `/etc/security/limits.conf`?

Comment: Uh. No. `ulimit` works by calling `getrlimit` and `setrlimit`. _Nothing_ writes to `/etc/security/limits.conf`, and the only thing that reads it is the pam_limits module. What part of my answer gave you the impression that it was otherwise?

Comment: Sry. What kinds of applications work by reading and writing from and to /etc/security/limits.conf?  Are they exactly those which rely on pam_limits module?

Comment: For example, is bash's signal handling trap for SIGQUIT implemented based on  both `/etc/security/limits.conf` and `setrlimit()`, so it reads from `/etc/security/limits.conf`, and calls `setrlimit()` to change the core file size limit to the values in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, and then tries to create a core dump file?

Comment: Again, __nothing__ writes to /etc/security/limits.conf in the course of normal operation; it only changes when the system is being upgraded or reconfigured, and the tools used that are typically things like `vi` and `dpkg`, which are general-purpose system administration tools. In principle, there could be applications that _read_ from limits.conf without using pam_limits to do it, but I don't know why anyone would bother, it doesn't look fun to parse.

Comment: Bash doesn't have a special handler for SIGQUIT and is not involved in the process of creating a core dump.  The kernel writes a core dump as part of the "default action" for SIGQUIT, if and only if the rlimit for core dumps is large enough; that rlimit may have been established by `login` according to what it says in limits.conf, or it may have been adjusted by hand using `ulimit`, or whatever.

Comment: I think you need to read a book on the basic architecture of Unix systems; your follow-up questions suggest you are confused at the level of basic design principles.  The usual recommendation is W. Richard Stevens' _Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment_.  There might be a better introductory text nowadays, but I don't know what it is.  (I learned nearly everything I know from the manpages and the POSIX specification, but I am That Kind Of Nerd.)

Comment: Thanks. I am reading APUE, which has made huge impact on me and it is still making. I don't find in APUE that `login` sets up the resource limits from `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Neither can I find that `login` sets up default signal handlers, for which  I have some confusions https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446947/where-does-a-bash-process-get-its-default-signal-handlers-traps